# Vue data binding doesn't work in functional component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, observable

When clicking the button, you will see `n` is getting bigger but the UI remains `1`

```js
<script>
let n = 1
function add() {
  console.log(n)
  return ++n
}
export default {
  functional: true,
  render(h, ctx) {
    return (<div>
      <h1>{n}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>click</button>
    </div>)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intended Behavior**

This is the intended behavior of functional components and the thing that makes them functional.  From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components):

> ...we can mark components as functional, which means that they’re stateless (no reactive data)
>
> Since functional components are just functions, they’re much cheaper to render.

**Explanation**

What this means-- and the reason `n` is not reactive-- is that `n` is not [`observable`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) and has no dependency management/watching.  This lack of dependency overhead is also the reason for the performance increase of functional components.  You get speed at the cost of observability, which is a nice tradeoff if you don't need it.  If you do, there would be no reason to use a functional component.

**How to proceed**

So, you could proceed to simply use a non-functional component, or, reason about whether it's possible to subdivide your functional component further and encapsulate only the reactive portions into a non-functional subcomponent.

**Other thoughts**

If you manually added observability to your functional component, you would get the behavior you wanted, though there's no reason to do this over using a non-functional component.  Notice the use of `observable`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
let state = Vue.observable({n: 1});

function add() {
  console.log(state.n)
  return ++state.n
}

export default {
  functional: true,
  render(h, ctx) {
    return (<div>
      <h1>{state.n}</h1>
      <button onClick={add}>click</button>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

(Note: You can use `render` functions in normal components as well.  I say this just in case you had a misunderstanding that a functional component was required for `render` functions.)

Comment: Thanks. really nice answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad it helped